# Pass variable from Parent Window Javascript Function to Popup Window Div

Tags: javascript, html, parameters

How do I pass the variable "appName" from the SerialPopUp function to the pop up window I create? Thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

```
        function SerialPopUp(appInfo)
        {

            appInfo=appInfo.split("\n");
            var appName = appInfo[1].trim();
            var appType = appInfo[5].trim();
            var url = appInfo[7].trim();
            url = appInfo[7].substring(9,appInfo[7].indexOf("&gt;")-17);
            var serialNum = "";

            if(appType == 'External Paid'){
                x = window.open(url, "Get Serial Number","resizable=1,status=1, width=700, height=250");
                x.document.getElementById("appName").innerHTML= appName;
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
if(appType == 'External Paid'){
            url = url + '?appName=' + appName;
            x = window.open(url, "Get Serial Number","resizable=1,status=1, width=700, height=250");
            x.document.getElementById("appName").innerHTML= appName;
        }
```

This will pass the variable to the pop up window in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Use a query string variable. Extra text here.